# change date format with alter table

Tags: php, mysql

I have script that daily download "test.csv" from client ftp, in that csv file I have one date field in the format ('mm/dd/yyyy') and table has field xd format ('yyyy-mm-dd').

I upload csv file using load data command.

Please suggest me how can i handle this situation.

If there is any way i can change date format with alter table command or load data have any option to convert to table format.

Any help will make my work easy.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can write a script to convert your date to a time and then convert the time into a new date.

Something like this:

$time = strtotime( $originalDate );

$newDate = date( 'yyyy-mm-dd', $time );

See the php documentation for exact syntax

Date: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php 
Time: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: That helps, but is there any thing I can able to make change in table structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can load the values into a user variable before assigning to the date field with [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'test.csv'
INTO TABLE test
(@date_value)
SET date_field = STR_TO_DATE(@date_value, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

A downside to this approach is that you must specify the columns you are importing to.